# php,symfony 2 filter case sensitive

Tags: php, symfony

I want to ignore case in a filter , My code:

```
if (strtolower(isset($filterObject['name'])) && null !== strtolower(($filterObject['name']))) {
    $queryFilter->addStringFilter("name", ($filterObject['name']));
}
```

Comment: my filter with this code is case sensitive.
my question what do I need to change to ignore case in a filter?

Comment: @GRafoKI: I guessed so from the context, but it would be best if the question itself is also written in the text above (just after the code for example), as it is a bit confusing without the question also directly mentioned there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore the casesensitivity of the addStringFilter by lowercasing the object
you would just have to use strtolower($filterObject['name']).
strtolower lowercases the string given.

On that note you are using strtolower on an isset function result which won't do a thing there (as isset returns no string).

So you should change your sourcecode to:

```
if (isset($filterObject['name']) && null !==  strtolower(($filterObject['name']))) 
{
    $queryFilter->addStringFilter("name", strtolower(($filterObject['name'])));
}
```

Btw one case you didn't check is if $filterObject['name'] is empty (not sure if it is possible as I don't know your remaining code. If it CAN be possible you want to add another and into the if:

```
&& $filterObject['name']
```

That would make sure that it is filled with more than an empty string.
Thus the if part would change to:

```
 if (isset($filterObject['name']) && $filterObject['name'] && null !==  strtolower(($filterObject['name'])))
```

Comment: Regarding the empty string: He doesn't have to add an expression, just use `null !=  strtolower(($filterObject['name']))` with `!=` instead of `!==`, this will be false for `null`, `""` or `0`

Comment: No it dosen't work , and now even the right word e.g 'Good' dosen't work anymore

Comment: Then my guess is that also the data itself that is filtered by queryFilter->addStringFilter has small and capital letters in it. 
You would additionally have to lowercase that data before the filter is added.
(I've looked around and didn't find the addStringFilter function is that a non standard symphony2 function....thus from a custom library?)

Comment: yes this is the function : 
    public function addStringFilter($field, $value)
    {
        $this->query->andWhere(sprintf('q.%s LIKE :%s',$field, $field));
        $this->query->setParameter($field, '%'.$value.'%');
    }

Comment: Try out:
$this->query->andWhere(sprintf('LOWER(q.%s) LIKE :%s',$field, $field));  

if that works I'll add it to my answer above.

Comment: Ok , So now It inverse the result If I put 'good' it works , but 'Good' displays 'no result '

Comment: Then try out one last thing:

$this->query->andWhere(sprintf('LOWER(q.%s) LIKE LOWER(:%s)',$field, $field));

Comment: No error : Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_STRING, got 'LOWER'")

Comment: It works I found the solution: sprintf('LOWER(q.%s) in the function. And strtolower(($filterObject['name']) in the controller . Thanks Thomas E. for help !